# How to connect from Docker container parse-server to a host Postgresql DB?

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have installed an instance of parse-server with docker. I have my DB on the Host, but when I run the docker, it says `error on connecting to the DB.`

```
docker run -t -d --name parse-server parseplatform/parse-server --appName appname --appId appid--masterKey masterkey --clientKey clientkey --databaseURI postgres://example:1234563@localhost/parse-server --serverURL http://sync.example.com:1337/parse --verbose --publicServerURL http://sync.example.com
```

And I am getting this error:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16) {
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 5432
}
```

I tried with `--network host` but parse-server is giving me `{"error":"unauthorized"}` using this docker.

I tried also using `-o 5432:5432`, but it said the port is used, because the instance running on the host.

How can I connect to the PostgreSQL on the host from the docker parse-server without using `--network host`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that 127.0.0.1 is not your host localhost address, but docker localhost's.

So, you have different options, but maybe It's better trying to connect parse-server to your host address connected with docker network: `172.17.0.X`.

Execute `ifconfig` in your host and see what's your IP address for docker network, and then, try to put it in your command:

```
docker run -t -d --name parse-server parseplatform/parse-server --appName appname --appId appid--masterKey masterkey --clientKey clientkey --databaseURI postgres://example:1234563@YOUR_HOST_IP_IN_DOCKER_INTERFACE/parse-server --serverURL http://sync.example.com:1337/parse --verbose --publicServerURL http://sync.example.com
```

You can have a look to [Setup a docker container to work with local database](https://superuser.com/questions/1254515/setup-a-docker-container-to-work-with-a-local-database)

Comment: Can't connect. and on the pg_hba.

# "host Docker access to DB"
host    all             all             172.17.0.1/16           scram-sha-256

Comment: found that using --network host still can connect to the DB and a reverse proxy will help me reach the out side, thank you.